# Installed Ubuntu 16.04 and windows wont boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-10

I first installed Ubuntu from a usb with rufus, after doing boot repair and such i can access grub and theres the windows (10) and ubuntu options but windows wont boot, just a black screen or computer restarts

Cant access the folder on the ubuntu installation either

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg18R.jpg

Comment: The solution here should fix your problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009786/ubuntu-16-04-boot-error-with-call-trace/1009789#1009789