# Ubuntu 16.04 boot error with call trace

Tags: 16.04, boot

I was using Ubuntu server 16.04 well and suddenly I got a boot error one day. The boot error message looks like the image below. What is the problem and how should I fix it?

[boot error with call trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThVcD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Fix boot issue's in Ubuntu :**

---

First boot into repair mode by pressing "e" while booting.

Then choose "Fix broken packages"

After that choose "Update GRUB bootloader"

Drop to ROOT shell.

replace /dev/sdX with your Ubuntu partition

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub
reboot
```

[image: recovery-mode]

**If this won't fix your boot issue use one of the following fixes.**

---

### **With Boot-Repair:**

**Login to Ubuntu with a live USB.**

In terminal use the following commands to install boot-repair :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair
```

[image: Boot-Repair]

**Click on Recommended repair to fix your boot.**

---

### **From the terminal :**

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo blkid
```

**Run the following commands to mount the Ubuntu partition at  /mnt/ubuntu, replacing /dev/sdX with the device name of your Ubuntu partition from the above commands:**

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu

sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt/ubuntu
```

**Run the following command to reinstall grub from the live CD, replacing /dev/sdX with the device name of the hard disk above:**

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/ubuntu/boot /dev/sdX
```

**Update grub :**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Reboot :**

```
sudo reboot
```

---

## **This will fix your boot issue.**

Comment: We can use this post to refer all boot issue's from ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will do what you explained. Can you tell me more about the cause of the error?

Comment: Different things can cause this error. Its often easy to fix. I don't know what cause this error in your case , since i don't know what you did before this error came up.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue, so that people know the question is answered.

Comment: I can not boot after the first method. I am trying to fix it with boot-repair, but I can not proceed with the "no internet connection detected" message after clicking "recommended repair". The internet connection is OK.

Comment: I can not boot Ubuntu at this time, how do I work in terminal?

Comment: I tried to disable the check internet connection in the option and tried again, and then I can not proceed with the message "Please try again" with the message "There is a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software source of Linux (sda1)