# Where to start troubleshooting Ubuntu 1804?

Tags: startup

I have this mix of being familiar with Linux from an enterprise standpoint (not trained, just familiar, RHEL) and barely using it from a consumer standpoint (I have a home server that is just setup to run Plex and backup over the network).

Yesterday when I went to go copy over to it I found that Synctoy was hanging.  So I went downstairs to boot it and it.. seems to get up to the Grub bootloader and then.. I hit enter to continue, the screen remains purple and the menu disappears.  I see a few flickers of hard drive LED and then nothing. for hours.

I haven't ruled out a HW problem yet, is there a way to see what the start of the OS is hanging on? Assuming the issue is software driven and not hardware?  thank you!!

(Edit: Once I can find the error, I can likely solve it, the problem is that I am unable to see any errors to act upon)

Comment: https://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-boot-repair-ubuntu-1315203

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009786/ubuntu-16-04-boot-error-with-call-trace

Comment: Try booting into recovery mode wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode and post feedback. Please be as detailed as possible. 
See also
maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu and howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot

Comment: I'm not sure how I got to the answer, but some combination of:

going to a previous kernel's recovery
checking the verbose output of the startup since I was able to get trace
led me to "waiting on a startup job for md0"

was able to comment out the raid in /etc/fstab
was able to see that the first disk in the array was no longer responsive.
I'm able to get into ubuntu now and further troubleshoot the array. thank you!